# Cancel upload process on react-native-firebase storage

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

Is there any way to cance uploading process in react native firebase?

I'm using RNFirebase `5.0.0`. In the documentation here https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/blob/docs_old/docs/modules/storage.md says that `uploadTask.cancel()` is not yet supported. Is there any work around to cancel the upload?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it doesn't say that, and according to this [issue](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1411) it's been implemented from version 5, you should try it

Comment: I tried. I got error message saying `.cancel() is not currently supported by react-native-firebase`

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: version `5.0.0`

Comment: This got cut from the `v5.0.0` release due to some last minute issues with RN 57 that needed fixing - I've got this tracking internally still though for the `v5.x.x` release line - so hopefully in `v5.2.x` or `v5.3.x` - we'd also welcome a PR and would be happy to mentor a PR through to completion - reach out on our Discord server if so.